Environment variables in Vite React during runtime
I am using Vite setup for my react application. Although I am using the environment variables in workflows file as docker arguments like this while building the image -
 docker-args: "--build-arg VITE_TOKEN=xyz
               --build-arg VITE_API_URL=localhost:8080"

It is working just fine when deployed on environment.
What I felt that while building the docker image, these environment added up into the image itself. While I am using Helm Chart(values.yaml)
env:
  VITE_TOKEN: "token"
  VITE_API_URL: "https://app.dev.org.io"

and I am trying to add the environment variables in values.yaml, these variables are not being replaced in my application.
Is there any way I can replace environment variables from values.yaml to the react vite application ?

No, those are set at build time. I've explained the problem and some of the alternatives on my blog: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Just wanted to write that your post helped me fix my setup for React running on IIS. Thanks!
